# Is there a way to modify how I'm using variables in a loop so that the order I'm initializing them does not matter?

Tags: rust

I'm fairly new to Rust, so not entirely sure how to properly title the question because I don't fully understand the error. I have the following simplified code which I'm using to parse command line arguments:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {

    let mut script: &str = "";

    // Get the commandline arguments.
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    // Loop through and handle the commandline arguments.
    // Skip the first argument; it's the name of the program.
    for arg in args.iter().skip(1) {
        let split: Vec<&str> = arg.trim().split("=").collect();

        if split.len() == 2 {
            match split[0]{
                "file" => { script = split[1]; }
                _ => { println!("Invalid parameter: {}", arg); }
            }
        } else {
            println!("Invalid parameter: {}", arg);
            println!("Parameters should consist of a parameter name and value separated by '='");
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
error: `args` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:25:1
   |
12 |     for arg in args.iter().skip(1) {
   |                ---- borrow occurs here
...
25 | }
   | ^ `args` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

When I change where the *script* variable is initialized:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {

    // Get the commandline arguments.
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let mut script: &str = "";

    // Loop through and handle the commandline arguments.
    // Skip the first argument; it's the name of the program.
    for arg in args.iter().skip(1) {
        let split: Vec<&str> = arg.trim().split("=").collect();

        if split.len() == 2 {
            match split[0]{
                "file" => { script = split[1]; }
                _ => { println!("Invalid parameter: {}", arg); }
            }
        } else {
            println!("Invalid parameter: {}", arg);
            println!("Parameters should consist of a parameter name and value separated by '='");
        }
    }
}
```

The error goes away. Based on the error and how the order that the variables are being initialized changes things, I think I'm making a fundamental mistake in how I'm using (borrowing?) the variables in the loop, but I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong and the proper way to fix it. Is there a way to modify how I'm using the variables in the loop so that the order I'm initializing them does not matter?

Comment: @Shepmaster I added a formal question at the end to try and clarify. Just because I can get the code to run doesn't mean I'm doing things properly, and I think this a symptom of an issue in how I'm using the variables in the loop. This issue came up because I was reorganizing my variable initialization for readability, so it's something I definitely want to resolve.

Comment: @Shepmaster I believe the OP didn't understand **why** changing the order appears to fix the problem. Seeking understanding of the underlying issues as opposed to blindly fiddling with statement order until the compiler accepts the code is something to be encouraged.

Comment: @user4815162342 sure, I have no qualms with someone seeking better understanding — but it's also worth us as answerers understanding what the OP is actually seeking before writing a pages-long answer or even a short answer that's completely tangential to the real question. And unfortunately, there's often a mentality of "just fix my code" (not true here, thankfully).

Comment: @Shepmaster Agreed, and you personally have contributed more than your fair share of pages-long answers. :) However, in this particular case it seemed (to me) quite clear what the OP was asking. "Based on the error and how the order that the variables are being initialized changes things, I think I'm making a fundamental mistake in how I'm using (borrowing?) the variables in the loop, but **I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong and the proper way to fix it.**" To someone knowledgable in Rust, the OP already fixed their problem. To the OP, the "fix" seemed like arcane and fragile magic...

Comment: @anjama FYI, there's also `splitn` which would allow your parameter values to contain the character `=` and usually you'd omit the collection item type (`let split: Vec<_> =` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: `script` refers to a portion of one of the strings allocated by `env::args()`. If you define `script` before `args`, then `args` is dropped first (as the compiler's message notes, "values are dropped in opposite order") and `script` points to deallocated memory. Your fix, defining the `script` after the `args` object, is correct.

To answer the edited question: the order of variables does matter when one of them is a reference to the other, and you are not allowed to change them arbitrarily. For an explanation of why that is so, read on.

In Rust, every reference is associated with a *lifetime*, the scope during which the reference is valid. To take an example from [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html), lifetimes are what prevents the following from compiling (and crashing):

```
let r;
{
    let x = 5;
    r = &x;
}
println!("r: {}", r);  // doesn't compile - x doesn't live long enough
```

In many cases, lifetimes are inferred automatically. For example, the following are equivalent:

```
{
    let x = "foo";
    let y: &str = "foo";
    let z: &'static str = "foo";
}
```

i.e. compiler will infer the static lifetime given the use of a string constant, which is statically allocated and exists during the entire execution of the program. On the other hand, the following uses a narrower lifetime:

```
// correct
let s = "foo".to_owned();  // allocate "foo" dynamically
let sref = s.as_str();     // points to heap-allocated "foo"
...
```

Here, `sref` is only valid for as long as `s` is valid. After dropping or mutating `s`, `sref` would point to uninitialized memory, which Rust carefully prevents. Inserting extra braces sometimes helps visualize the scopes:

```
// correct - sref cannot outlive s
let s = "foo".to_owned();
{
    let sref = s.as_str();
    ...
}
```

On the other hand, if you write them backwards, it doesn't compile:

```
// incorrect, doesn't compile
let mut sref = "";
let s = "foo".to_string();
sref = s.as_str();
```

To see why, let's insert more explicit scopes:

```
// incorrect, doesn't compile
{
    let mut sref = "";
    {
        let s = "foo".to_string();
        sref = s.as_str();
    }
    // <-- here sref outlives s
}
```

This is essentially the same as the example from the book, and it is obviously not allowed to compile! And now it should be a bit clearer what the compiler means by "values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created". The fact that `s` is declared *after* `sref` means that it is effectively nested in an inner scope, which is why it will be dropped *before* the stuff in the outer scopes. `sref` referring to anything in `s` means that after the inner scope, `sref` is pointing to uninitialized memory.

To get back to your code, `env::args()` returns an [`Args` object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/struct.Args.html) whose `Iterator` implementation yields dynamically allocated `String`s. Although you start off by assigning a static `&str` to `script`, the lifetime of the `script` reference is determined as an intersection of the scopes of all assigned values. In this case these are the static scope from the first assignment and the scope of `args` from the second assignment, and their intersection is the `args` scope, which ends up being used as the reference lifetime. Moving `script` declaration after `args` places the `script` reference into an inner scope compared, ensuring that it always refers to a live object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think this is largely just not something I'm used to with my experience in other languages. The two let statements on their own where *args* and *script* are first created are completely unrelated, and without the subsequent code, run just fine. Having their order matter based on code somewhere else is an interesting new experience for me.

Comment: @anjama I can understand how that can be confusing. On their own the declarations run fine because in that case `script` never refers to anything in `args`, it really is just a reference to a static string valid for the entire duration of the program.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to modify how I'm using variables in a loop so that the order I'm initializing them does not matter?

Yes, you can avoid borrowing at all by cloning the value:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let mut script = None;

    for arg in env::args().skip(1) {
        let mut parts = arg.trim().splitn(2, "=").fuse();

        match (parts.next(), parts.next()) {
            (Some("file"), Some(name)) => script = Some(name.to_owned()),
            (Some(other), Some(_)) => {
                println!("Invalid parameter: {}", other);
            }
            (Some(other), None) => {
                println!("Invalid parameter: {}", other);
                println!("Parameters should consist of a parameter name and value separated by '='");
            }
            (None, _) => {}
        }
    }

    let script = script.expect("file is a required parameter");
    do_thing_with_script(&script);
}

fn do_thing_with_script(_script: &str) {}
```

This also avoids allocating multiple `Vec`s. There's also a theoretical/potential memory savings as we don't have to keep the entire argument string in memory, just the parameter. On the flip side, there's a bit more allocation.

Profiling is always the right path, but it has yet to be my experience that command line processing is a large resource usage of a program. To that end, I advocate doing whichever route makes your code easiest to understand, maintain, and which gives your end users the best experience.
Usually that means using a library.

---

If you have your heart set on borrowing, then [user4815162342's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46864930/155423) explains why you have to have the thing you are borrowing from outlive the borrow.